# Accessing iframes from a Chrome content-script extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to alter a popular web app when loaded. Unfortunately, most of the UI of that web app is rendered inside an iframe, and although the address of that iframe matches my `content_scripts` match declaration, the user script only gets invoked for the top frame.

Q: Is there a method of accessing HTML rendered inside an iframe from a Chrome content script extension? If yes, what permissions and other manifest options should I specify? Thanks.

Comment: Is this relevant for you? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37920

Comment: No, it isn't. The iframe is not injected by the extension, but by the original web app.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've resolved the problem. The following option has to be specified in the content_scripts section of the manifest.json: `"all_frames": true`. Without it, the script is only applied to the top frame.

// Sometimes one just has to RTFM carefully.

Answer (score 10):

Even `"all_frames": true` doesn't seem to help in the case of iframes without @src. This is discussed in the bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20773, which also covers some workarounds, including getting the `contentDocument` of the iframe element in the source page, e.g. `$('a', $($("#canvas_frame")[0].contentDocument))`.

This bug is not exactly the problem you were having (you wanted to load your content script inside the iframe, not interact between the iframe and the outer frame) but I think that most people who have one of the problems will have the other one as well.