# Can't access content of iFrame because of Cross domain restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, iframe

I am writing a google chrome extension to auto fill the "Leave feedback" forms on my eBay account.

When I run my extension I am on this site:
http://my.ebay.com/ws/....

and the sites that loads in the iframe have this format:
http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/....

and when I try to interact with the iFrame, I am unable to.

How, with code examples please, can I gain access to the contents of the iFrame so that i can execute this line

```
        frame.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('radiopad')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = true;
```

Please let me know if you need any  more info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing iframes from a Chrome content-script extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937355/accessing-iframes-from-a-chrome-content-script-extension)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it because it comes from a different domain. See [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)